# How to make admin theme option with image slide show?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

How to make admin theme option with image slide show so admin can change image dynamicly (user can upload and change the image and title slider) as a slideshow on the webpage? Thank you for any feedback.

Note: without any plugin

Comment: You know that already: Show us your research efforts.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use custom post type "slideshow" and multiple custom field "image" only. Plugin named Types should do the trick for you, but you'll still have to code the slideshow

Comment: how to make it without plugin?

Answer (score 0):

use Header Slideshowplugin for header img conwort  in images slider 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/header-slideshow/